# Bash - How to find the longest txt file in a folder?

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to write a script which finds the longest txt file in a folder. I literally have no idea how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "the longest text file"?

Comment: Largest in size or longest filename? What designates a "txt" file --  a ".txt" at the end of the filename?

Comment: Longest in terms of what? Bytes? Characters? Lines? Have you determined how to find out the length of a file?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly:

Assuming all the files has TXT extension, you can do

`du -b *.txt | sort -n | tail -n1`

and if you want something a little bit more specific:

```
for a in *;do
    f=$( file -i $a | grep -Eo ": ([a-z\/]+);" )
    [ "$f" == ": text/plain;" ] && du -b $a
done | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there other files in the directory? Can you give us the directory listing?

But barring that I would try something like

```
ls -Sl $(file * |grep text |cut -d " " -f 1|sed 's/://')
```